# How to select the groups which a certain user doesn't join with Mysql?

Tags: mysql

Given three data table, `theUser`, `theGroup`, `membership`:

```
theUser:(*user_id*, username),
theGroup:(*group_id*, groupname),
membership:(*group_id*, *user_id*)
```

For instance, group `2` has user `007` and `008`, the `membership` should be like:

```
group_id      user_id
2             007
2             008
```

Now I wish to select the groups that user `008` HAS NOT BEEN IN. Could you tell me how to do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several different ways to do this.  Here's one with an `outer join / null` check:

```
select g.*
from thegroup g
   left join membership m on g.groupid = m.groupid and m.userid = '008'
where m.groupid is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 select distinct group_id 
 from theGroup 
 where group_id not in 
(select group_id from membership where user_id='008');
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I think it will work . Will it not?

Comment: Yes even using not exists will work. IN that the query remains same , just we need to replace not in with not exists

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * FROM `theGroup` WHERE `group_id` NOT IN(SELECT `group_id` FROM `membership` WHERE `user_id` LIKE '008')

Comment: Hmmm, not sure why this was downvoted... I selected the entire data instead of just the group_id and assumed `group_id` is unique in table "theGroup" (since it should be). So not sure why this is wrong.

Comment: I did not vote down your answer. But why is it `user_id LIKE '008'`? And maybe you should adjust the format. Anyway, thanks for you answer!

Comment: `LIKE` is almost like `=` if you do not use wildcards (`%`), the performance impact is negligible since the SQL engine converts it into `=` . I agree that `=` is a better fit here while `LIKE` adds more flexibility if later you want to filter based on more complex user_id patterns. Seeing as your user_id is not an INT but rather a string, I (maybe wrongly) assumed you have extra data built in like complex IDs: XY where X means some sort of different group and Y is the numeric id. Otherwise it makes little sense to have the user_id as a string and not an INT. That is why I made it with `LIKE`.