# How to select messages from two different tables in a specific order with Mysql?

Tags: mysql

There are totally five data tables:

```
theUser (*id*, name)
theGroup (*id*, name)
Membership (*group_id*, *user_id*)
gpMsge (*id*, sender, receiver, content, time)  # message within group
idMsge (*id*, sender, receiver, content, time)  # message between user and user
```

The relationship among `theUser`, `theGroup` and `Membership` has been explained from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307783/how-to-select-the-groups-which-a-certain-user-doesnt-join-with-mysql/37307940#37307940). Now I want to extract the conversation(`gpMsge` and `idMsge`) and display the name of corresponding sender (`theUser` and `theGroup`) in the order of the newset message in that conversation. Indeed the business logic is exactly the same with `Whatsapp`. In the first part, the sender names (individual user name if the conversation is p2p or group name if it is within group) show with the order by the time of the newest message in that conversation. And below each sender name, there are should be five newest message in that conversation. In the second part, all group with no conversation is displayed (no need to specify the order in this part).

The difficulty for me now is the order of the conversation as the `gpMsge` and `idMsge` is isolated. How can I sort the `time` value in each table and get the name of `theUser` and `theGroup` in a table? Thank you in advance!

Comment: in your table "gpMsge" there is no info about the group a sender x and a receiver y can be both menbers in more than one group, so how to figure out if a message was sent in a specific group?

Comment: @Amani the receiver in the gpMsge is group id.

Comment: okay i see , my mistake ...

Comment: I have updated my answer with a demo take a look if that answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "UNION" so you can compare the time between the two different tables

This query will list the last 5 conversations from both tables.

```
SELECT id,sender,receiver,content,time
FROM gpMsge
UNION
SELECT id,sender,receiver,content,time
FROM idMsge
ORDER BY time DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

#### UPDATE

full query will be like this::

```
 SELECT US.name AS sender,GR.name AS receiver,content,time 
     FROM gpMsge AS GM 
     LEFT JOIN theUser AS US ON GM.sender=US.id 
     LEFT JOIN theGroup AS GR ON GM.receiver=GR.id 
 UNION 
 SELECT US.name AS sender,UR.name AS receiver,content,time 
    FROM idMsge AS UM 
    LEFT JOIN theUser AS US ON UM.sender=US.id 
    LEFT JOIN theUser AS UR ON UM.receiver=UR.id 
 ORDER BY time DESC
 LIMIT 5;
```

[see demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce31d6/2)

If you want to select one specific sender or receiver you have to add this a WHERE clause:

This query will select all conversations which sent to the receiver having id number 2: direct messages to this user or messages which been sent to a group having this user as a member.

For your last question you can add an extra field to check if a message was sent from a user in or outside a group, this can be some text or an int ...

```
SELECT  US.name AS sender,GR.name AS receiver,content,
        "This is a message in a group" AS sent_from,time 
    FROM gpMsge AS GM 
    LEFT JOIN theUser AS US ON GM.sender=US.id 
    LEFT JOIN theGroup AS GR ON GM.receiver=GR.id 
    WHERE receiver IN (
           SELECT group_id FROM  Membership WHERE user_id=2
    )

UNION 

SELECT  US.name AS sender,UR.name AS receiver,content,
        "This is a message from a user" AS sent_from, time
   FROM idMsge AS UM 
   LEFT JOIN theUser AS US ON UM.sender=US.id 
   LEFT JOIN theUser AS UR ON UM.receiver=UR.id 
   WHERE receiver=2

ORDER BY time DESC  
LIMIT 5;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce31d6/7)

Get all groups having a specific user as a member and having no message received yet:

```
SELECT id,name 
FROM  Membership AS M 
JOIN theGroup AS G ON M.group_id=G.id 
WHERE user_id=2 
AND group_id NOT IN (SELECT receiver FROM gpMsge);
```

[SEE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5f3c7/2)

Comment: But maybe you should change the the second `theUser` in `gpMsge` to `theGroup`.

Comment: your welcome ....please notice that in the query i have joined the first table(second join to get the receiver name) by the user table not the group table.. I updated the link take a look.

Comment: Thanks. But seems that it is retrieve all the conversation. But what I want actually is all conversation whose receiver has a certain id, for instance , 2

Comment: the receiver is sometimes a group so do you want to list only conversation sent to a specific user and not group?

Comment: Conversation sent to a specific user and the group which the user has joined. That kind of group can be retrieved by:
`select g.id from theGroup g, theUser u, membership m, where g.id = m.group_id and u.id =m.user_id `

Comment: I see what u mean .. see my answer I have apdated once again.

Comment: That's perfect now. Thanks! But I have one more question, why not use nature join instead of left join? Won't it keep the unnecessary result?

Comment: So should I use natural join?

Comment: And how can I know a certain row is from group or individual user?

Comment: yes in your case you can use JOIN or INNER JOIN when joining theGroup table because some users have no Groups. For your last question see updated second link.

Comment: Do you mean the link of demo? Seems that the connection has some problems. Is there any difference with the code in your answers?

Comment: I have also updated my answer not only the link, please take a look and tell me if that what do you really need.

Comment: Thanks, it works like a magic. My last question is how can I get the groups that the specific user has been but HAS NOT MESSAGE YET ? Thanks!

Comment: I added this to my answer for the user 2

Comment: Tons of thanks for you patience and help! You have saved my life.